# Problem nesting 3 columns inside bootstrap4 column

Tags: bootstrap-4

In the following code, I was expecting the 3 columns nested within column number 2 from the left (A of 3, B of 3 and C of 3), to look as "columns", instead they are showing like rows. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Fiddle:
[Fiddle with code](https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/s7r4owmn/24/)

Code text:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         q1 of 4
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"><!--Issue is 
         <div class="col"> 
            A of 3 
         </div>
         <div class="col">
            B of 3 
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            C of 3 
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         q3 of 3
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         q4 of 4
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another `.row` to wrap the inner columns.

https://www.codeply.com/go/c6fmh4Fypj

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            q1 of 4
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    A of 3
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    B of 3
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    C of 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            q3 of 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            q4 of 4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and always great help. One day, I may get to learn some of this stuff...